# remove border on :first-child

Tags: css

I'm trying to remove the border with the first child pseudo but I cant get it to work.

this is the class im working with

```
.main:not(.home-page) > section article h2  {
  margin-top: 1em;
  padding-top: 1em; 
  border-top: 1px dotted #ccc;  
}
```

so I tried this

```
.main:not(.home-page) > section article h2:first-child{
  border-top: 0px dotted #ccc;
}
```

but that didn't do the trick. Any other ideas ?

Comment: Can you please fiddle demo for this?

Comment: Why is this not working? Can you show us some HTML code too?

Comment: `border-top:0` is enough

Comment: @ChiragVidani

Hardik Patel solved it for us :)

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this

```
.main:not(.home-page) > section article:first-child h2{border-top: 0px dotted #ccc;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set the respective color to `transparent` ([MDN on `border-top-color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-top-color)):

```
.main:not(.home-page) > section article h2:first-child{
  border-top-color: transparent;
}
```